# Add created element after closest third div within the row

Tags: javascript

I have six blocks, each block has a click function to trigger the contentBlock() snippet.

I'm trying to get the contentBlock() to create the element and display the created div after the closest third item (After the third within the row), currently, the below creates the div and displays after every third item on both rows.

How do I get the created element to sit after the closest third item? E.G The first three triggers would display content under the first row and the next three under the next row.

Any and all suggestions would be appreciated.

[image]

```
function contentBlock() {
    const items = document.querySelectorAll('.js-item');
    items.forEach(function (item, index) {
        if((index + 1) % 3 === 0) {

            /* Create Element */
            const elem = document.createElement('div');
            elem.classList.add('js-content-block', 'col-12');
            elem.innerText = 'Content Block';
            item.parentNode.insertBefore(elem, item.nextSibling);

        }
    })
}
```

```
   <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 js-item">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card__thumbnail">
                        <img src="#" alt="#">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__title">
                        <h3>Name</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__body">
                        <p>role</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__actions">
                        <div>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#" title="#">Number</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#" title="#">Email</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button class="js-toggle" data-count="0" aria-label="#">+</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 js-item">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card__thumbnail">
                        <img src="#" alt="#">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__title">
                        <h3>Name</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__body">
                        <p>role</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__actions">
                        <div>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#" title="#">Number</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#" title="#">Email</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button class="js-toggle" data-count="1" aria-label="#">+</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 js-item">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card__thumbnail">
                        <img src="#" alt="#">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__title">
                        <h3>Name</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__body">
                        <p>role</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__actions">
                        <div>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#" title="#">Number</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#" title="#">Email</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button class="js-toggle" data-count="2" aria-label="#">+</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 js-item">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card__thumbnail">
                        <img src="#" alt="#">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__title">
                        <h3>Name</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__body">
                        <p>role</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__actions">
                        <div>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#" title="#">Number</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#" title="#">Email</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button class="js-toggle" data-count="3" aria-label="#">+</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 js-item">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card__thumbnail">
                        <img src="#" alt="#">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__title">
                        <h3>Name</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__body">
                        <p>role</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__actions">
                        <div>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#" title="#">Number</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#" title="#">Email</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button class="js-toggle" data-count="4" aria-label="#">+</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 js-item">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card__thumbnail">
                        <img src="#" alt="#">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__title">
                        <h3>Name</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__body">
                        <p>role</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__actions">
                        <div>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#" title="#">Number</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#" title="#">Email</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button class="js-toggle" data-count="5" aria-label="#">+</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I can't see any questions in your post. Could you add one?

Comment: It would be great if you could provide the HTML and CSS on which this code is run, in a [mre]. You can use Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar). Currently, we don't know how `js-item`s are laid out.

Comment: @HereticMonkey HTML added.

Comment: @MatviiHodovaniuk question updated.

Comment: it would be really helpful if you could elaborate your question in a better way that explains the problem you are facing , i didn't understand what do you mean by block and closest to what exactly , plus how are you triggering the function ,  will you share your try and clarify your goal please

Comment: @HijenHEK


I have 6 blocks, each has a button - on click it will create an element. I would like the new element to display after the third (last) item within the row. So the first 3 blocks would show the new element between and the next three blocks would show their new content below them as well. 

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: all 3 buttons create div under their respective row ?example first three buttons have same behavious ?

Comment: @HijenHEK that's correct.

Comment: so let me get this clear , below the first row you mean after the third one right ? and the content div wont have the same behaviour as the first ones right ?

Comment: @HijenHEK If you click any of the first three it will create the new div and place it below the first three, if you click any of the next three (second row) it would add the new div below these three.

Comment: if the content divs added wont have the same behavious i dont see why you are using a loop and testing the modulat etc , thats why i asked if they will have the same behaviour , you could simply hav id's for those final divs and insert next to them , but still this is not eloquent since youa re using bootstrap why dont you use two rows , that would be better .